# swap positions on tap - corona sdk

Tags: lua, coronasdk

How can I look at two taps and transition the 2 to swap positions with each other? 
For example: I tap on object[1] and then tap on object[2] and then they would transition and swap places. How would you guys attempt at setting this up?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somthing like that:

```
local last = nil

local circle1 = display.newCircle(display.contentCenterX - 50, display.contentCenterY - 50, 25)
circle1.fill = { 0.0, 0.6, 1.0 }
local circle2 = display.newCircle(display.contentCenterX + 50, display.contentCenterY + 100, 25)
circle2.fill = { 1.0, 0.5, 0.0 }
local circle3 = display.newCircle(display.contentCenterX + 75, display.contentCenterY - 100, 25)
circle3.fill = { 0.4, 0.5, 0.0 }

local function onTouch( event )
    local target = event.target
    if event.phase == "ended" then
        if last == nil then
            last = target
        elseif last ~= target then
            transition.moveTo( last, { x=target.x, y=target.y } )
            transition.moveTo( target, { x=last.x, y=last.y } )
            last = nil
        end
    end
end

circle1:addEventListener( "touch", onTouch )
circle2:addEventListener( "touch", onTouch )
circle3:addEventListener( "touch", onTouch )
```

Comment: Hey Maicon, thanks for help. Some of the positions don't swap however. Anything left and right will swap but anything long distance gets muddled up and vanishes. Is this because of the way I am spawning? Its currently spawning 3 objects in a row and they stack up in 3's

Comment: Ah I see where the problem is occurring. It looks like its having an issue with swapping positions when they are moving downwards (via another transition.) For some reason its not a problem if the object is left or right of the selected one. Any ideas on a solution for this ?

Comment: Maybe you need to set, before animation, "last.isRunning=true" and "target.isRunning=true" and when complete, set to false. And check "elseif last ~= target and not last.isRunning and not target.isRunning".

Answer (score 0):

I would save the coordinates of the first tap, and then on the tap event of the second tap, transition the second object to the first's coordinates and the first to the second tap's coordinates.

A little something like this. This is psuedo-code. Just to help present the idea.

```
local firstObject
local secondObject
local coordX, coordY
function firstTapEventListener(event.target)
   coordX = target.x
   coordY = target.y
end

function secondTapEventListener(event.target)
   firstObject.x = target.x
   firstObject.y = target.y
   target.x = coordX
   target.y = coordY
end
```

Comment: Thanks Brett, thats perfect